# Protractor >> Error: spawn Unknown system error -86 >> From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

So I have been working in Protractor for my end to end tests of my Angular application. It has been working for as long as I have been developing the tests. Then most recently it gave me the below error. Originally I had thought it had to do with Chrome and Chromedriver not being compatible. So I went to update chrome and chromedriver that did not work for me. I then tried to install Chrome version 88 and its corresponding chromedriver and that produced the error still. So I would like to know what could the issue be with my dev environment.

```
[16:55:10] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[16:55:10] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_87.0.4280.88.zip
[16:55:10] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_87.0.4280.88.zip
[16:55:10] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_87.0.4280.88
[16:55:10] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_87.0.4280.88 up to date
[16:55:11] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:55:11] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:55:12] E/launcher - spawn Unknown system error -86
[16:55:12] E/launcher - Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:407:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:548:9)
    at exec (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:116:27)
    at /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:219:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/Users/gregoryrothstein/dev/sso_service/aicure-dashboard/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[16:55:12] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

Versions:

Google Chrome: Version 88.0.4324.77 (Official Build) beta (x86_64)

Protractor: @7.0.0

webdriver-manager: @12.1.7

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Any updates?

Comment: This is addressed in a duplicate StackOverflow question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618558/osx-fix-selenium-chromedriver-launch-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-bad-cp

Comment: After reading the the above StackOverflow posted. Updating Protractor worked for me and fixed my issue I was having here. [sudo npm install -g protractor]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved in `webdriver-manager@12.1.8`

Make sure to install it globally and locally

Comment: I had to do this: `npm i -D webdriver-manager@12.1.7 && npm dedupe && npm update webdriver-manager && npm uninstall webdriver-manager`