# Getting this error when running ng e2e on mac with visual studio code

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e, e2e

**Setup** :

```
@angular/cli@8.1.2
@ionic/cli@6.12.3
cordova@10.0.0
npm@6.14.10
“protractor”: “~5.4.0


Mac OS : Catalina
```

This is the error I am getting

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
:information_source: ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[12:08:58] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:08:58] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:08:58] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[12:08:58] E/launcher - Error: Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
    at exec (/Users/sunilharan/Documents/Projects/IONIC/App_NAME/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:116:27)
    at /Users/sunilharan/Documents/Projects/IONIC/App_NAME/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:219:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[12:08:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

This same setup is working on another machine running on M1 chip. I have tried on different computers but not working on any of them except my M1 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Then port 8100 is reserved, but are u sure ur running ionic serve and not ng serve?

Comment: @MostafaHarb ionic serve is working fine. This error appears on ng e2e command.

Comment: As per Seamus McCarthy's answer, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618558/osx-fix-selenium-chromedriver-launch-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-bad-cp -- it can likely be fixed by running "npm uninstall protractor && npm install protractor" in your terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the latest chromedriver on MacOS. Please see detailed resolutions in this ticket.

"As a general solution, simply avoid using the chromedriver that has _m1 in its filename if you are on an Intel mac."

[OSX fix Selenium Chromedriver launch error spawn Unknown system error -86 Bad CPU type in executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618558/osx-fix-selenium-chromedriver-launch-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-bad-cp)